# Operator Overloading with Vectors of Vectors

Tags: c++, matrix, stl, operator-overloading, stdvector

I am new to C++ and OOP. In my assignment, we are told to overload operator +, -, *, / etc for performing operations on matrices. I am reading two matrices from a txt file and have created two objects of Matrix class with two matrices populated into it.
I am trying to overload the operator+ to perform addition on the values of both matrices and provide me with a new resultant vector of vectors.
I've tried several different approaches but I always seem to get this same error "expression: vector subscript out of range"

matrix.h:

```
//
// Created by kd2ma on 12/7/2021.
//
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(char const* src, int size, bool isMat2Present);
    T initMatrix();
    void printMatrix(vector<vector<T>> myMatrix) const;
    vector<vector<T>> getMatrix() const;
    T getSize() const;
    ~Matrix();
    vector<vector<int>> operator+(Matrix m);
    void addMatrix(const Matrix &m, const Matrix &mm);

private:
    fstream fInput;
    T *size = new T(sizeof(int));
    T *currentInt = new T(sizeof(int));
     vector < vector < T >> matrix_r;
     vector < T > matrix_c;
    bool isMat2Present;
    vector<vector<T>> result_matrix;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, vector<vector<int>> m);

#endif //MATRIX_H
```

matrix.cpp

```
//
// Created by kd2ma on 12/7/2021.
//

#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(char const *src, int size_a, bool isMat2Present_a) : fInput(src) {
    *size = size_a;
    *currentInt = 0;
    isMat2Present = isMat2Present_a;
}

template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::initMatrix() {
    if (!isMat2Present) {
        fInput.ignore();
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *size; j++) {
                fInput >> *currentInt;
                matrix_c.push_back(*currentInt);
            }
            matrix_r.push_back(matrix_c);
            matrix_c.clear();
        }
        fInput.ignore(4);
        fInput >> *currentInt;
        T operation = *currentInt;
        cout << "operation = " << operation << endl;

        return operation;
    }
    else if(isMat2Present == true) {
        fInput.ignore(39);
        fInput >> *currentInt;
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *size; j++) {
                fInput >> *currentInt;
                matrix_c.push_back(*currentInt);
            }
            matrix_r.push_back(matrix_c);
            matrix_c.clear();
        }
    } return 0;
    }

template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::printMatrix(vector<vector<T>> myMatrix) const  {
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *size; j++) {
            cout << myMatrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
vector<vector<T>> Matrix<T>::getMatrix() const  {
    return matrix_r;
}

template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::getSize() const  {
    return *size;
}

template<typename T>
 void Matrix<T>::addMatrix(const Matrix &mm, const Matrix &m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *size; j++) {
        result_matrix[i][j] = mm.matrix_r[i][j] + m.matrix_r[i][j];
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
vector<vector<int>> Matrix<T>::operator+(Matrix m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getSize(); j++) {
            result_matrix[i][j] = matrix_r[i][j] + m.matrix_r[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result_matrix;
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix() {
    delete size;
    delete currentInt;
}


template class Matrix<int>;             //resolve linker error


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, vector<vector<int>> m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.size(); j++) {
            os << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        os << endl;
    }    return os;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int size;
    bool mat2 = false;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(argv[1]);
    fin >> size;

    Matrix<int> m1(argv[1], size, mat2);
    int operation = m1.initMatrix();
    m1.printMatrix(m1.getMatrix());

    if (operation < 4) {
        mat2 = true;
        Matrix<int> m2(argv[1], size, mat2);
        m2.initMatrix();
        m2.printMatrix(m2.getMatrix());
        m1.addMatrix(m1,m2);
    }

/**/
}

/*    int operation = m1.initMatrix();
    m1.printMatrix(m1.getMatrix_1());
    m1.getMatrix_2();
    m1.printMatrix(m1.getMatrix_2());
    cout << operation << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "hello";
    m1.addMatrix(m1.getMatrix_2());
    cout << m1.getAdd();
   // cout << m1.getAdd();

}*/
```

> my.txt
> 4
> 1 3 4 7
> 4 6 3 4
> 1 4 2 3
> 9 99 88 77
> op 3
> 1 4 5 2
> 4 7 2 3
> 1 2 3 4
> 3 1 3 4

Comment: The operation `m1 + m2` should return a new value `m3` of the same type. In your case `Matrix<T>`.

Comment: It's also a bad habit to create member variables that are really used as local variables.

Comment: *"I always seem to get this same error 'expression: vector subscript out of range'"* -- on which line? What is the value of the subscript you are using on that line? What is the size of the vector on that line?

Comment: @JaMiT it says line 1483, I am not sure how to check size of the vector on that line :|

Comment: @KeyurMaru ??? How do you do your debugging? Over a dozen lines without basic debugging skills? Scary. Anyway: `std::cerr << "The size of my_vector is " << my_vector.size() << ".\n";` (or use a debugger that knows how to report the size).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you elaborate a little more? cus when I made another object m3 for storing the result of m1+m2, the compiler gave an error saying = operator not overloaded, will I have to first overloaded = operator?

Comment: Considering that you have pointers and a destructor you should follow [the rule of three or file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). So yes you need an assignment operator. Or stop using pointers and use the rule of zero.

Comment: As for the error, you of course need to update the return type of your `operator+` function to return `Matrix<T>`. I also suggest you check e.g. [this operator overloading canonical implementation reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations).

Comment: And a note regarding those pointers: `T *size = new T(sizeof(int));` makes no sense! It allocates a *single* object of type `T` and attempt to initialize it with `sizeof(int)`. Why is `size` or `currentInt` pointers? What is even `currentInt` used for? That seems like it should be a local variable in some function, not a member variable.

Comment: @JaMiT I am sorry, I thought vector size meant something else when talking about that specific line.  When I used the debugger, it showed that the function correctly gets the size 4 of both of my matrices, but the loop doesn't run at all, it throws subscript out of range right when it enters in the loop at i and j = 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changing operator+ return type to Matrix<T> didn't work for me. It gave the same error vector subscript out of range. This is how my new operator+ function looks like. 

 `template <typename T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix &m) {
    Matrix<int> mq("ABC",4,true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            mq.matrix_r[i][j] = m.matrix_r[i][j];
            cout << mq.matrix_r[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return mq;
}`

Comment: Will both the matrices you attempt to add have the exact same size? Will the destination matrix have that size as well? Have you checked for and tested these things?

Comment: Another note about the `size` member variable. What if you create a `Matrix<std::string>`? Does it make sense that `size` is a pointer to `std::string`? Why not plain `size_t size;`?

Comment: Yes, now I understand the issue with the size and I just changed the size and currentInt to be static variables to fix that. Yes, I have confirmed that the matrices I am trying to add have the exact same size. Moreover, when I tried to create a 2-D array in the operator+ function and use it like:
`int newArr[4][4];
newArr[i][j] = matrix_r[i][j] + m.matrix_r[i][j]` and it works as intended but it don't work when using vector like:
`newVector[i][j] = matrix_r[i][j] + m.matrix_r[i][j]`

Comment: @KeyurMaru -- This `Matrix` attempt is getting more convoluted and error-prone.  Get rid of **all** the pointer usage.  You are using `std::vector<T>`, there is no need for pointers.  Once you get rid of the pointers, you don't need `delete`.  Once you don't need `delete`, the destructor can be totally removed or declared as `=default`.  Once you do that, then returning and passing `Matrix` by value will automatically work.  Once you do that, the problem gets reduced down to only checking if the `Matrix` have the same size.  You kill multiple birds with a single stone by removing the pointers.

Comment: @KeyurMaru -- Also: `fstream fInput;` -- remove this from `Matrix`.  This by itself thwarts the copying of `Matrix`.  Why is the stream part of the `Matrix` class?  Input/Output specifics should be outside of the class, not a part of it.  The `Matrix` class shouldn't care where the data comes from to populate itself.  It should a simple function that takes, in whatever form, data to populate the matrix.  Maybe a sequence of values, maybe an array, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, already got rid of all pointers in the code as well as removed the destructor. I kept the stream part in the Matrix class because I wasn't sure how to parse the input file correctly without access to the stream inside of the Matrix class. But I am still not able to add both matrices, same error vector subscript out of range.

Comment: When you use `newVector[i][j] = ...` is the vector resized properly? A default-constructed vector will be *empty* and any indexing into it will be out of bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie okay I am going to try removing stream from class and pass data to it using an array

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that is what is making all the problems, my new vector is empty. Trying to resize it properly now.

Comment: @KeyurMaru In your `operator +`, you are passing `Matrix` by value.  Having an `fstream` as a member should have triggered a compiler error;  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/704963f83a052c8d).  However, you should have passed it by const reference anyway.  That's what I meant by the `fstream` member totally screwing up copying.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you boss, I am now making modifications according to all of the suggestions

Comment: @KeyurMaru *"it showed that the function correctly gets the size 4 of both of my matrices"* -- Both? Isn't the problem on a line with **three** matrices, not two? (Of course, that's just a guess on my part since you did not clearly indicate in your question which line crashes.)